# JavaScript color game default colors

Tags: javascript

So I am doing a color picking game with JavaScript. I have the functionality of everything working perfectly. But I noticed a bug. When you first load onto the page or even refresh the page. The values of all squares are purple. If you click new colors or hard or the easy button different rgb values are populating. Why am I getting a default of purple values when I start the page or refresh? I am trying to have it so when the page is started it randomizes the rgb values without me or the user having to hit new colors to initiate the game.

heres my code

~html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title>Color Game!</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>

<div id="stripe">
    <button id="reset">New Colors</button>
    <span id="message"></span>
    <button id="easyBtn">Easy</button>
    <button id="hardBtn" class="selected">Hard</button>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

~css

```
body {
    background-color: #232323;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Avenir";
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;

}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    background-color: steelblue;
    margin: 0;
}



#stripe {
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.selected {
    background: blue;
}
```

~ JS

```
var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
var numSquares = 6;
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
var easyBtn = document.getElementById("easyBtn");
var hardBtn = document.getElementById("hardBtn");

easyBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    hardBtn.classList.remove("selected");
    easyBtn.classList.add("selected");
    numSquares = 3;
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        if(colors[i]) {
            squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        } else {
            squares[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

})

hardBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    hardBtn.classList.add("selected");
    easyBtn.classList.remove("selected");
    numSquares = 6;
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        squares[i].style.display = "block";
    }
})

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // generate all new colors
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    // pick a new random color from the array
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    // change colorDisplay to match picked color
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    // change colors of squares
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
    h1.style.backgroundColor = "steelblue";
})

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    // add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    // add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    // grab color of clicked square
    var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
    // compare color to pickedColor
    if(clickedColor === pickedColor){
        messageDisplay.textContent = "Correct!";
        resetButton.textContent = "Play Again?";
    changeColors(clickedColor);
    h1.style.backgroundColor = clickedColor;
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
        messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again";
    }
    });
}

function changeColors(color) {
    //loop through all squares
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {

    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

function pickColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];
}

function generateRandomColors(num) {
    // make an array
    var arr = [];
    // repeat num times
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(randomColor());
    }
    return arr;

}

function randomColor() {
    // pick a "red" from 0 - 255
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    // pick a "green" from 0 - 255
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    // pick a "blue" from 0 - 255
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

Comment: Switch you variable declaration order (make sure numSquares is before colors) `var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares); var numSquares = 6;` and it will populate colors as you expect it to.

Comment: Hey thanks Lance your absolutely right. I forgot to switch numsquares before the variable colors. Thanks man!

Comment: Awesome, I'll go ahead and make it an answer if you want to mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS hard codes the purple:

```
.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
```

You need to add an event handler for when the page loads to call your color changing code like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Call color changing code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure numSquares is declared before colors.

So

```
var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
var numSquares = 6;
```

becomes

```
var numSquares = 6;
var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
```